# Azure SQL Database Publish Issue

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, azure, azure-sql-database

This is a new clean database, created on Azure this morning.
Entity Framework did a build and seed, but when I come to publish my project from VS2017, using update database in the publish settings, I get this error:

```
Web deployment task failed. (An error occurred during deployment plan generation. Deployment cannot continue.
The Element or Annotation class SqlDatabaseOptions does not contain the Property class CatalogCollation.
The Element or Annotation class SqlDatabaseOptions does not contain the Property class CatalogCollation.
Learn more at: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_EXECUTING_METHOD.)
```

I followed the link, but the error is a little generic, so I'm no further on.

Any ideas how to solve this please?

**EDIT**
Just for clarity, I can use entity-framework to update the database manually, the issue is when I select update database in the publish settings.

```
PM> enable-migrations -enableautomaticmigration
Checking if the context targets an existing database...
Code First Migrations enabled for project backend.
PM> update-database
Specify the '-Verbose' flag to view the SQL statements being applied to the target database.
No pending explicit migrations.
Running Seed method.
PM>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same error, and restarted my web app in the Azure portal.  There was a locking problem.  That solved it for me.

Comment: Trying as we speak